# Online Push Notification Services

Tags: service, notifications, push, token

I have developed an app and it is published sucessfully on iOS and Android. I have integrated push using the App42 Push Notification API which works great, but is quite expensive. I am storing the device tokens on my peronal MySQL-database which is hosted on my webpage. I am wondering if there are any other Push Notification Services that supports sending of push notifications using PHP/HTML using device tokens and API keys?

I have researched following:
Parse
OneSignal
PushWoosh
PushWizard
Pushover

None of them seems to support sending of push notifications using PHP or HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly all of them support sending push notifications via a RESTful interface/web-service which needs to be consumed by your PHP.

Parse: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#push-notifications

OneSignal: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

I am sure few of the others also support sending push notifications via an API.

Comment: You can also take a look at http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/createmessage and http://gomoob.github.io/php-pushwoosh.